# A basis of a field extension $K \subset L$ spans $L(C)$ over $K(C)$ for any subset $C$ of a field $M\supset L$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $K \subset L \subset M$ be fields; $\{\beta_1, ..., \beta_k\}$ a basis for $L$ over $K$ and $C$ a subset of $M$. Then $\{\beta_1, ..., \beta_k\}$ generates $L(C)$ over $K(C)$ (where $K(C)$ is the smallest field containing both $K$ and $C$).

Some help proving that? I know $L[C]$, the smallest ring containing $L$ and $C$, is generated by the basis, but the inverses of these elements are being problematic...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- $L$ is the smallest field containing $K$ and $\beta_1,\ldots , \beta_k$.
- $L(C)$ is the smallest field containing $L$ and $C$.
- $K(C)(\beta_1,\ldots , \beta_k)$ is the smallest field containing $K$, $C$, and $\beta_1,\ldots \beta_k$.

Comment: $K$ doesn't contain $L$. I'm not sure exactly what you were trying to say, but once I started thinking on those terms, I figured it out! Thanks! (:

Comment: @violeta Glad to hear.  I mixed up $K$ and $L$; it should be okay now.